# Best C++ approach to store unique elements

Tags: c++, data-structures

[image: Figure]

I drew a picture to describe the data-structure I am looking for.

What is the most efficient C++ way of declaring such a data-structure, where:

1. The size is fixed in the first dimension and dynamic in the second. In the second dimension, it dynamically increases in size on insertion of elements.
2. Only unique elements are permissible in each column (in figure). The ordering is not important

I have explored the use of `std::set` and something as `set< set<int> > array`. But can the solution please include how the data-structure is declared, initialized and accessed.

Comment: Looks like a `std::array<std::set, N>` to me, where `N` is the fixed size.

Comment: Could you please then post a solution where its declared, initialized and accessed?

Comment: although you have a fixed size array, I would still go with `std::vector<std::unordered_set>`

Comment: What operation are you optimizing for?

Comment: Without knowing how the elements are assigned to each "column" it's hard to tell.

Comment: @maxim It is an O(n^2) for loop iterating through all elements in turn

Comment: @Lorenzo Unique elements are inserted, and non-unique elements are not.

Comment: @dr_rk What operation: is it insertion, search, removal?

Comment: The ordering of elements is not important

Comment: @maxim After insertion, I will compute the average of each "column"

Comment: This is hash_set aka unordered_set exactly

Comment: @dr_rk You can do running average without having to store all elements, did you know that?

Comment: @maxim to ensure uniqueness, it must require some kind of storage. But you make a good point, it could have been done with running averages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could create and use such a structure

```
// Example program
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::array<std::set<double>, 4> bins = {std::set<double>{1.0, 2.0, 5.0},
                                            std::set<double>{7.0, 2.0},
                                            std::set<double>{3.0, 9.0 ,1.0},
                                            std::set<double>{7.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0}};
    bins[1].insert(3);

    for (auto const& bin : bins)
    {
        std::cout << "average: " << std::accumulate(bin.begin(), bin.end(), 0.0) / bin.size();
        std::cout << "\tvalues : ";
        for (auto const& value : bin) std::cout << value << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Output](http://cpp.sh/3ms2)

```
average: 2.66667    values : 1 2 5 
average: 4          values : 2 3 7 
average: 4.33333    values : 1 3 9 
average: 3          values : 0 1 4 7
```

**Edit**:
If you do not have access to C++11, you can use `vector` instead of `array`, but know that it will not be of fixed size. You also can't use `auto`. So you can change your code to

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::set<double>> bins = {{1.0, 2.0, 5.0},
                                          {7.0, 2.0},
                                          {3.0, 9.0, 1.0},
                                          {7.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0}};
    bins[1].insert(3);

    for (std::vector<std::set<double>>::iterator itBin = bins.begin()
         itBin != bins.end();
         ++itBin)
    {
        std::set<double> const& bin = *itBin;
        std::cout << "average: " << std::accumulate(bin.begin(), bin.end(), 0.0) / bin.size();
        std::cout << "\tvalues : ";
        for (std::set<double>::iterator itValue = bin.begin();
             itValue != bin.end();
             ++itValue)
        std::cout << *itValue << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems STL `array` is only part of C++ since 2011

Comment: you can use std::vector<std::set<int>, 4> or a array of std::set<int> bins[4] as well.

Comment: question: auto const or const auto. either fine?

Comment: @911 They are equivalent, your preference.

Comment: @911 `std::vector< std::set<int>, 4 >` is NOT a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
int main()
{
    const unsigned int FIXED_SIZE=10;
    std::array<std::set<int>, FIXED_SIZE> data;

    data[1].insert(4);
    data[2].insert(100);
    data[2].insert(200);

    // Calculation:
    for( auto a : data )
    {
        int mw=0;

        for ( auto s: a )
        {
            mw+=s;
        }
        if ( a.size() )
        {
            mw/=a.size();

            std::cout << "MW in class is " << mw << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "class was empty" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

if c++11 is not possible, simply replace std::array with 
`std::set<int> data[FIXED_SIZE]`
and replace the for loops with the *old fashioned* `for` loops.

Comment: Not sure exactly how your elements are going to get populated, but if they're getting pushed in one at a time, you could consider adding a running average to this solution, such that you wouldn't have to iterate over all of them at the end.

Comment: I only read the comments from the questions author. There he wants the mw as result so I simply did that as example. There are always lots of improvements but not asked for :-)

Comment: Oh, this solution is fine.  My comment was a suggestion for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 only, taking into account that the order doesn't matter, and assuming that the "fixed-size" of the first dimension is only known at runtime:

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

template <class T>
class MyDataStructure
{
public:

    typedef std::unordered_set<T>     column_type;
    typedef std::vector<column_type>  row_type;

    MyDataStructure()
        { clear(); }
    explicit MyDataStructure( size_t n )
        { resize(n); }

    void clear()
        { m_data.clear(); }
    void resize( size_t n )
        { m_data.resize(n); }

    // Number of columns
    inline size_t size() const 
        { return m_data.size(); }

    // Access column k (eg for iteration)
    inline const column_type& column( size_t c ) const { return m_data[c]; }
    inline       column_type& column( size_t c )       { return m_data[c]; }

    // Insert in column k
    inline void insert( size_t c, const T& val ) 
        { column(c).insert(val); }
    inline void insert( size_t c, T&& val ) 
        { column(c).emplace(std::forward<T>(val)); }

private:
    row_type m_data;
};
```

You can easily add a member variable to keep track of the total number of elements if needed. You can also easily implement elements removal (`erase`) and search (`find`). If you want a non C++11 solution, remove the emplace-insertion and replace `unordered_set` by `set`.

Answer (score 0):

For C++, use `std::tr1::array` + `std::set`

```
#include <tr1/array>
#include <set>

int main( )
{
    std::tr1::array< std::set<float>, 7> foo;

    foo[1].insert(1.7F);
    foo[1].insert(2.3F);
    foo[6].insert(9.0F);

    return 0;
}
```

For C++11, use `std::array` + (`std::set` / `std::unordered_set`)

```
#include <array>
#include <unordered_set>

int main( )
{
    std::array< std::unordered_set<int>, 3> obj;

    foo[1].insert(1);
    foo[1].insert(2);
    foo[3].insert(1);

    return 0;
}
```